# Text subscript within math environment ($$)

Tags: subscripts

How can I make a subscript of 'p' in fp(x) = ...

I have this code right now, but I think there's a better way:

```
$f\textsc{$p$}(x)=x^3-x^2+px+1$
```

Comment: `\textsc` is nothing to do with subscripts: it selects caps and small caps font.

Comment: The answer below will not work in expl3 mode. See  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/612655/250119 instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subscripts in math mode are initiated using `_`, as in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$f_p(x) = x^3 - x^2 + px + 1$
\end{document}
```

For sub-scripting multiple items, brace them using `_{...}`. If you want to write text in the subscript, use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\text` for the prevailing text font, or `\mathrm` for a forced upright font:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem
\begin{align*}
  f_{\text{prob}}(x)   &= x^3 - x^2 + px + 1 \\
  f_{\mathrm{prob}}(x) &= x^3 - x^2 + px + 1
\end{align*}
\end{theorem}
Some regular text.
\begin{align*}
  f_{\text{prob}}(x)   &= x^3 - x^2 + px + 1 \\
  f_{\mathrm{prob}}(x) &= x^3 - x^2 + px + 1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case I would use `\mathrm`. With `\text` the font will be the one current outside the formula, which may not be upright.

Comment: I've never known, why `\mathrm` (or `\mathup`) instead of `\textrm` (or `\textup`)?

Comment: @Manuel use `\mathrm` if you want the content set as math and `\textrm` if you want the content set as text. Compare `\mathrm{hello world 1 - 1}` and `\textrm{hello world 1 - 1}`